# Inconsistent Setting Variables CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

So I have the following in my controller:

```
$employee_options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Employee.id' => $this->employee_id),
    'recursive' => 4,
);

$employees = $this->Employee->find('all', $employee_options);
$this->set('employees', $employees);

$initial_dept_id = $this->Employee->field('department_id', array('id' => $this->employee_id));
```

first I had it like this

```
$index_chosen = $this->Employee->field('index_chosen_section', array('id' => $this->employee_id));
$this->set('initial_dept_id', $initial_dept_id);
$this->set('$index_chosen', $index_chosen);
```

Then I changed $index_chosen to this, when I couldn't get it to work:

```
$index_chosen = $employees[0];
$this->set('initial_dept_id', $initial_dept_id);
$this->set('$index_chosen', $index_chosen);
```

Here is my view:

```
<pre>
  <?php print_r($employees[0]) ?>
</pre>
<pre>
  <?php print_r($index_chosen); ?>
</pre>
```

Both approaches(in controller) resulted in $index_chosen to show nothing. In the second approach, I am printing the same thing, but only the first shows. Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Please always specify the version of the framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$` in the first half of your `->set()`:

```
$this->set('$index_chosen', $index_chosen); // <-- NO

$this->set('index_chosen', $index_chosen); // <-- YES
```

In the past, I believe Cake would also auto camelcase your variables, so depending which version you're using, after making the above change to remove the `$`, if the `$index_chosen` variable is still not showing in your view, you could try `$indexChosen` instead (which is the recommended case for your variables anyway).

```
$indexChosen = $employees[0];
$this->set('indexChosen', $indexChosen); // <-- EVEN BETTER
```

---

**Side Note:**

When setting multiple variables, instead of putting each on it's own line, it's common practice to use [PHP's `compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
$this->set(compact('initial_dept_id', 'index_chosen'));
```